# Isn't $f(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta}) = b + \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} = b + w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \dots + w_D x_D$ the linear regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, linear, supervised-learning

Chapter **1.2.1.5 Uncertainty** of [*Probabilistic Machine Learning: An Introduction* by Kevin P. Murphy](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html) says the following:

> We can capture our uncertainty using the following **conditional probability distribution**:
> $$p(y = c \mid \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta}) = f_c(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta}) \tag{1.7}$$
> where $f: \chi \to [0, 1]^C$ maps inputs to a probability distribution over the $C$ possible output labels. Since $f_c(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta})$ returns the probability of class label $c$, we require $0 \le f_c \le 1$ for each $c$, and $\sum_{c = 1}^C f_c = 1$. To avoid this restriction, it is common to instead require the model to return unnormalized log-probabilities. We can then convert these to probabilities using the **softmax function**, which is defined as follows
> $$\text{softmax}(\mathbf{a}) \triangleq \left[ \dfrac{e^{a_1}}{\sum_{c^\prime = 1}^C e^{a_{c^\prime}}}, \dots, \dfrac{e^{a_C}}{\sum_{c^\prime = 1}^C e^{a_{c^\prime}}} \right] \tag{1.8}$$
> This maps $\mathbb{R}^C$ to $[0, 1]^C$, and satisfies the constraints that $0 \le \text{softmax}(\mathbf{a})_c \le 1$ and $\sum_{c = 1}^C \text{softmax}(\mathbf{a})_c = 1$. The inputs to the softmax, $\mathbf{a} = f(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta})$, are called **logits**. See Section 2.5.2 for details. We thus define the overall model as follows:
> $$p(y = c \mid \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta}) = \text{softmax}(\mathbf{a})_c(f(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta})) \tag{1.9}$$
> A common special case of this arises when $f$ is an **affine function** of the form
> $$f(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta}) = b + \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} = b + w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \dots + w_D x_D \tag{1.10}$$
> where $\mathbf{\theta} = (b, \mathbf{w})$ are the parameters of the mode. This model is called **logistic regression**, and will be discussed in more detail in Chapter 10.

Isn't $f(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{\theta}) = b + \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} = b + w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \dots + w_D x_D$ the *linear* regression model, not *logistic* regression?

Comment: A generalized linear model (of which logistic regression is an example) is nothing more than a 'standard' linear regression and a *link* (and variance) function - here the softmax is mapping the linear log-odds to the probability scale.

Comment: When the author writes, 'This model is called logistic regression', he is referring to equation $(1.9)$, not equation $(1.10)$.